# Compiler throws error after Miktex update from February 10, 2021

Tags: hyperref, font-encodings

After yesterdays update to hyperref version packed February 10, 2021, I get this error using Lualatex:

> ("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty"

> Package: hyperref 2021-02-08 v7.00i Hypertext links for LaTeX
>
> ("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/hycolor/hycolor.sty" Package:
> hycolor 2020-01-27 v1.10 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO) )

> ("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/letltxmacro/letltxmacro.sty"
> Package: letltxmacro 2019/12/03 v1.6 Let assignment for LaTeX macros
> (HO) ) @linkdim=\dimen420 \Hy@linkcounter=\count551
> \Hy@pagecounter=\count552
>
> ("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def" File:
> pd1enc.def 2021-02-08 v7.00i Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
> ) ("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX
> 2.9/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref-langpatches.def" File: hyperref-langpatches.def 2021-02-08 v7.00i Hyperref: patches for babel
> la nguages ) ("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX
> 2.9/tex/generic/intcalc/intcalc.sty" Package: intcalc 2019/12/15 v1.3 Expandable calculations with integers (HO) )
> \Hy@SavedSpaceFactor=\count553 Package hyperref Info: Option `draft' set` false' on input line 4058. Package hyperref Info: Option
> `colorlinks' set` true' on input line 4058. Package hyperref Info:
> Option `frenchlinks' set` false' on input line 4058.
>
> ! LaTeX Error: Encoding scheme `PU' unknown.
>
> See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation. Type  H
>   for immediate help.  ...
>
> ```
>                                                l.4058 \ProcessKeyvalOptions{Hyp}
>                             ?  ("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/hyperref/puenc.def" File: puenc.def 2021-02-08 v7.00i Hyperref: PDF Unicode definition (HO) )
> ```

I do have the file C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/hyperref/puenc.def.

Trying to reinstall puenc.def yields yields "no such package".

Usual recommended fixes, like Miktex console "refresh font map files" or running pdflatex once prior to lualatex don't work.

How can I fix this? How can I get back to latest hyperref?

Remark: Just hitting ENTER when compile stops yields a PDF which looks ok (at first glance).

Comment: that will be resolved in the next update which is already on ctan. For now move setting like pdfauthor=XXX from the hyperref options to \hypersetup. See also https://github.com/latex3/hyperref/issues/172

Comment: Thanks, Ulrike!